# Unable to remote to Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: networking, xrdp, rdp

I have Ubuntu 20.04 which also has Security Onion installed on it.

I'm trying to connect to my Ubuntu from a Windows 10 machine. XRDP has been installed on Ubuntu. I can connect if I'm logged in but I get the black screen. I've read it means you need to be logged out. It seems that the connection is getting denied. I can connect to the Security Web Interface no problem.

I'm fairly new to Linux. Does Linux have startup types such as automatic, automatic (delayed) or manual like Windows? If so, how can I view this information?

Comment: If you log out of Ubuntu can you then connect via xrdp?

Comment: See this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237288/20-04-xrdp-kde-plasma-connect-issue/1238801#1238801